# plotting contours from a three column array

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour

I have a three column array, contains two parameters which are the x and y axes, and the Chi-square of these two parameters. I should make a meshgrid of these two parameters and then plot 1-sigma, 2-sigma, and 3-sigma contours, considering the Chi-square values. How can I do it in matplotlib?

Here is my code:
x (which is the second column in the "1.txt" file) and y (which is the third column) should be arranged from min to max, in order to make x and y axes, I thought it can be done using meshgrid. And z (the first column in the "1.txt" file) is the Chi-square.

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.mlab import griddata
x = np.genfromtxt('1.txt', usecols=(1))
y = np.genfromtxt('1.txt', usecols=(2))
z = np.genfromtxt('1.txt', usecols=(0))
plt.figure()
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y) 
Z= griddata(x,y,z,X,Y)
contour=plt.contour(X,Y,Z)
plt.show()
```

this code confront with the error:
"RuntimeError: To use interp='nn' (Natural Neighbor interpolation) in   griddata, natgrid must be installed. Either install it from http://github.com/matplotlib/natgrid or use interp='linear' instead."
When I use interp='linear', running the code would last a long time without any result. Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: Without any sample data, attempted code and if possible a desired sample output, it will be difficult to obtain a concrete solution here. You should have a look on how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are creating a "grid" of **all** values in your columns. Instead you would want to create a regular grid of numbers in an increasing order. E.g. using 100 values between the minimum and maximum of the data

```
X = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), 100)
Y = np.linspace(y.min(), y.max(), 100)
Z = griddata(x, y, z, xi, yi, interp='linear')
contour=plt.contour(X, Y, Z)
```

Also see this [example](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/griddata_demo.html).

Note however that `matplotlib.mlab.griddata` has been removed in newer versions of matplotlib, but is available with `from scipy.interpolate import griddata`, as shown in the [new example](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/irregulardatagrid.html), which also has the a newer option with `axes.tricontour`.

Consider directly plotting a triangulated contour using your original values `x,y,z`,

```
plt.tricontour(x, y, z)
```